# Reflection on Nested Types adds methods. Is this a bug?

Tags: .net, reflection

I'm using reflection to obtain methods on a nested type/s and they always have extra methods that don't exist.

this appears to be a difference between:

```
info As **TypeInfo**
Dim methods As IEnumerable(Of MethodInfo) = info.DeclaredMethods
```

vs

```
info As **Type**
Dim methods As IEnumerable(Of MethodInfo) = info.GetMethods
```

The extra methods returned are:

```
Equals, GetHashCode, GetType, ToString
```

Is this a bug in .Net or am I missing something?
It seems to happen with other nested types also, so I'm trying to understand why?

```
Public Class TestHasNested

    Public Property bla As String

    Public Class NestedItem

        Public Property MyProperty As Integer

    End Class
End Class
```

Comment: Those methods are members of `System.Object`, which all classes have as a base class.  You are getting those members via inheritance.

Comment: Use the overload of `GetProperties` that takes a `BindingFlags`, and pass it `DeclaredOnly` to exclude base class members.

Comment: except I don't get them for any other classes, except the nested types

Comment: Please add code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: It's kinda complicated, It's from a reflection loaded assembly, so it seems to be a difference between the new reflection api vs the old. Or Type vs TypeInfo. Can't find an easy way to get a TypeInfo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I was using two different reflection classes `TypeInfo` vs `Type`

```
Type.GetMethods()
```

vs

```
TypeInfo.DeclaredMethods()
```

I also discovered you can call `Type.GetTypeInfo()` to obtain the TypeInfo

```
    Dim valueNested As New TestHasNested.NestedItem()

    Dim tpNested = valueNested.GetType()

    Dim methNested As IList(Of MethodInfo) = tpNested.GetMethods()

    Console.WriteLine("Type.GetMethods")
    For Each m As MethodInfo In methNested
        Console.WriteLine(m.ToString())
    Next

    Dim methNestedDeclared As IList(Of MethodInfo) = tpNested.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredMethods()
    Console.WriteLine()

    Console.WriteLine("TypeInfo.DeclaredMethods")
    For Each m As MethodInfo In methNestedDeclared
        Console.WriteLine(m.ToString())
    Next
```

**Result:**

**Type.GetMethods**

```
Int32 get_MyProperty()
Void set_MyProperty(Int32)
Boolean Equals(System.Object)
Int32 GetHashCode()
System.Type GetType()
System.String ToString()
```

**TypeInfo.DeclaredMethods**

```
Int32 get_MyProperty()
Void set_MyProperty(Int32)
```